# How to find four nearest neighbour points using Knn?

Tags: matlab

I am using MatLab and normal KNN classify do is just find the nearest point. But for my application I need the four nearest points. I have a grid in xy plane. Each point in the grid has a specific RSSI value. I use unknown RSSI as the sample. I have a training set already with me for each point on the grid. So I can get the nearest point. But how can I get the nearest points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [`knnsearch`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html), just use

```
IDX = knnsearch(X,Y, 'K', 4);
```

(`'K'` defines the number of nearest neighbours)

If you are using [`fitcknn`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationknn-class.html),

```
mdl = fitcknn(X,y,'NumNeighbors', 4)
```

If you are using [`ClassificationKNN.fit`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationknn.fit.html),

```
mdl = ClassificationKNN.fit(X,y,'NumNeighbors', 4);
```